# Could my flying primates exist?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, evolution, winged-humans

A long time ago, a group of primates diverged into three main groups: Imps, Angels, and possibly fairies? Some characteristics of flying primates include:

- being 4.1 feet
- having pterosaur-like wings
- are tetrapods instead of Hexapods like classical Angels
- are erect bipeds (similar to gibbons or humans)
- are monogamous (similar to kiwis or gibbons)
- have a prehensile tongue, and owl like feet
- are covered in white fur
- are capable of flight
- are quite slender
- live in large groups
- having a surprisingly human like face
- have aggressiveness on par with chimpanzees
- are omnivorous
- have long hair which can range from blond to black (optional)
- are smarter than chimpanzees but not as smart as a human
- are capable of taking off from the ground with a running start but usually live up in trees and high up elevations

Given these characteristics, what species of primate could they have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to them?

NOTE: Magic does not exist in my story

Comment: How functional are their wings? Are they able to glide? Support their own weight? Take off from the ground? IMHO the answers to their flight capabilities are going to be drive yes/no of feasibility.

Comment: This seems like an Anatomically correct series question and you should format it to fit that format if it is.

Comment: The whole list reads to me like they evolved from birds not primates - large birds for sure, but ...

Comment: @Nicolai eh, flying squirrels are a thing.

Comment: What's a *surprisingly humanoid looking face*? Surprising to whom? To the reader, or to other creatures who meet them?

Comment: Just a note of realism, despite all the lies of the Jurassic Park/World movies, we have known since the 1800s that Pterosaurs (which are not classified as dinosaurs) actually had fur more like marsupials or bats. Although they are not directly related to those creatures, if you would like to make that description more realistic, your "angels" will end up looking more like "fallen angels" or vampires... Just a thought.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle i know Pterosaurs  had fur like feathers I just didn't think it would be important to add sense my angels are primates not Pterosaurs

Comment: almost your angel, @icewar1908, in Zanzibar island: https://www.brut.media/us/entertainment/the-zanzibar-red-colobus-a-strange-and-endangered-primate-11ac0788-49bf-4f2a-abda-d801a8c02d71

Comment: The one thing I say is not that likely is the long prehensile tail, since that would weight it down a fair bit and risk hindering flight, even for its size. I'd recommended instead giving it feet like those of an owl (zygodactly with a toe capable of coming forward) or even a long, prehensile tongue to do the handling parts, since those would be better ways to give it dexterous structures without weighting it down too much

Comment: @ProjectApex fair enough i've been considering giving them prehensile tongue and dexterous feet to make up from their lack of thumbs so i'll add that in

Comment: @icewar1908 the moment you said their wings were pterosaur like and they were 4 feet tall I immediately thought about [pteranodons](https://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/dinosaurs/dinos/Pteranodon.shtml), and I'm mostly sure your angels could have similar anatomic traits. By the way, even without opposing digits intellect is possible. Think about how crows (use their beak to make and handle tools) and dolphins (basically no visible digits) are remarkably intelligent.

Comment: @sphennings  despite being about winged primates None of the answers to the Anatomically Correct Angels question address a tetrapod variation, lacking human arms or having a long prehensile tail, tongue, and feet

Comment: We already have questions asking about the viability of flying monkeys evolving. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57187/evolutionary-pressure-for-creation-of-flying-monkeys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its easy to exist.

However, a pterosaur wing will use their superior limbs. Take in consideration Human inteligence evolve due the able to make tools. I'm not sure how this animal would evolve some kind of high inteligence without an opposite thumb. Unless than - this looks like weird - they use their inferior limbs to use tools, as the [Dug specie from Star Wars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dug).

Since they fly, is more probably they have a long tail to bring stability rather than a short one.

All this said, your angel creature would evolve from arboreal monkeys from American continent, with a long phehensile tail. Jump between different trees provide the pressure to appear one membrane between the limbs, as in the flying squirrel, and in the successive generations superior hands convert into wings.

Evolutinary pressure to inteligence is kinda hard to compare in this way. We can see capucchin monkeys with a [justice sense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meiU6TxysCg), and [use tools like stone age humans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MgHBvp1uwk). Crows are master of logic, even without an opposite thumb, as show [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbSu2PXOTOc) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZerUbHmuY04). Since your angels will evolve to similar human face is easy to make they evolve to [facial expressions](https://news.cornell.edu/stories/2014/03/study-facial-expressions-evolved-optical-needs) and complex language, that are important steps. One other important boost in inteligence evolution is [use of fire to cook food](https://www.ted.com/talks/suzana_herculano_houzel_what_is_so_special_about_the_human_brain/discussion?referrer=playlist-how_does_my_brain_work): more calories per portion, no demand all awake time of day hunting for food and soft food demand less strong teeth, opening room in the head to one brain expansion.

Your angel-monkey will demand one giant amount of calories to movement and metabolism, then the use of fire will provide a boost to improve inteligence without, although, they be smart enough to compare with humans. Issues in use inferior limbs instead superior limbs probably its a good reason to no evolve high as humans too.

The [japanese macaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_macaque) is the only (only I know) specie with white fur. This happen cause snowfall where they live. I cant wonder another good reason to one primate evolve white fur or hair beside it, even hominids no evolve white skin before explore northern regions. Highlands are a good bet too. Like humans, its easy build the specie evolving in a tropical region, expand to tall trees florests where fly evolve and after explore high montain regions, like the Amazon - Andes region looks like. White fur and hair will happen there, with brownish hair as recessive gene happen in some individuals.

Comment: For some reason this made me think of Sharovipteryx haha.

Comment: Man, this look weird but is really a good one and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Easily. When it comes to biological evolution and selective pressures, the sky's the limit. Nothing you've suggested is entirely unreasonable, the only thing that might be a stretch is the wings.

I would imagine they'd need to be roughly bat shaped in order to really effectively fly (or glide), and many different branches of biological life have covergently evolved to develop flight, from mammals to insects to arachnids to reptiles.

One example of a possible selective pressure is a canopy with trees of many varying heights. The need to survive a jump when escaping predators or ambushing prey could easily pressure skin flaps to slow or guide a free fall.